# How to logout from multiple iscsi targets

Tags: linux, storage

I want to logout/delete from multiple iscsi targets

`iscsiadm --mode node --logoutall=all`

this will delete all the connections present in the system.

How do I delete multiple nodes in just one command.

for example the ip addresses are:

```
10.100.0.101
192.168.1.101
10.100.0.111
192.168.1.111
10.100.0.121
192.168.1.121
10.100.0.131
192.168.1.131
10.100.0.141
192.168.1.141
```

Comment: Can't you leverage a `while`?